# Security issues of storing a password in a CMD line parameter

Tags: windows, security, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows batch script which executes a program `psexec` that requires a password. Rather than having the password visible in plain-text within the batch script, I simply have `%1` in the batch script, and I'm passing the password as a CMD line parameter instead.

I have `@echo off` to prevent the password from being displayed back, and I have an `exit` at the end of my batch script to close the CMD window once executed (so you can't scroll up and read the password). I realize that this still isn't entirely secure, as the CMD line parameters are stored in memory, and the password could potentially be read.

What I would like to know is:

1) How long are CMD line parameters held in memory? Are they removed from memory after the "exit"?

2) What is required for a hacker to access the memory to view the password? Is this "easy" to do?

3) Is this any less safer than storing the password in an environment variable (see link below)?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19911.how-to-use-an-environment-variable-as-a-password-credential-to-run-a-batch-script.aspx

Comment: Your interest in keeping your password secure in the local session is very laudable, but it is much less valuable than keeping your password secure in the remote session. After all you can't control the remote system, and it could potentially be more insecure. So the first advice is don't use alternate credentials when executing remote commands. Use your local login instead. Having said so, and if you really need to enter alternate credentials, then your method sounds ok enough to me.

Comment: My main concern would be that `psexec` sends passwords over the network in cleartext.  Having a batch script manipulate passwords isn't best practice, but it isn't a major risk in practice: any attacker who could take advantage of it could probably obtain the password anyway no matter what you did (e.g., using a keylogger).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Harry, I think the latest version of psexec (after v2.1) encrypts the password and command:

"Note that the password and command are encrypted in transit to the remote system."

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Comment: Some good points about the overall security here. To answer your specific questions. 1) The command history buffer remains as long as the command window is open, so an exit will force that to be cleared. Rather than forcing an exit though, you might like to clear the screen and the wipe the command buffer: `cls` and `doskey /reinstall` 2) They'd need to be watching what you type, have a keylogger installed or be trawling your memory. 3) I actually think your approach (+ cls & doskey /reinstall) is probably marginally safer than storing an environment variable as it should be quicker overall.